# How to apply this function?

Tags: functions, algebra

I have defined functions `f[x]`, `g[x]`. How can I let them act on variable `x` (I want to put the name of these functions inside the parentheses)

```
(f + a + g) @ x
```

such that this equals to

```
f[x] + a x + g[x]
```

Comment: Through will do what you want, provided inside the parenthesis are only functions. E.g.: `f0[x] = a x; f2[x_] = 2 x; f3[x_] = 3 x^2;
Through[( f0 + f2 + f3)[x]]` gives `2 x + a x + 3 x^2`

Comment: Or use a pure function: `(f[#] + a*# + g[#]) &@x`

Comment: From what assumption do we now that `a` of `x` (i.e., `a[x]`) is to be a `multiplication`?

Comment: @gwr - the OP gives the desired result of `f[x]+ a x+ g[x]`

Comment: `Through[(f + (a*# &) + g)[x]]` should be enough—the only thing that needs to be altered is `a`, such that you're actually using the function "multiply by `a`" instead of the constant `a` as a function itself. (Contrast with `Through[(f + a + g)[x]]`, which is not what you want.)

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, I am aware of it, but it needs explanation because the (wished for) algebra only works out, if it is made clear, that a is "implicitly" defined as a function?

Comment: `a` is not a function.  `Function[x,a*x]` or `a*#&` is a function.

Comment: @cvgmt Well, exactly, but then it is kind of weird algebra imho.

Answer (score 3):

Is your motivation to reduce the amount of typing do you need to do?  I assume you are already aware of solutions such as `(f[#] + a*# + g[#])& @ x`, mentioned in the comments.

If so, my advice is not to try to do this. Mathematica is a programming language. It needs to be understood first by computers, not humans. Thus, it needs to be precise and unambiguous. Traditional mathematical notation, as used in textbooks, is extremely ambiguous. You, as a reader, can understand what is meant only because of the context, and because of knowing what is "reasonable" and what is "commonplace". For example, $f$ is usually used for functions and $a$ for numbers, but this is mere convention. Even so, there are chances for misunderstandings. Such notation is not suitable for computers.

What happens when computers try to interpret such notation anyway? Just try playing with Wolfram|Alpha for an hour, and see how many times it takes your input to mean something else than what you wanted.

---

Thus, functions cannot be added directly in Mathematica with `+`. In some languages, it may be possible to implement this, because those languages may have stronger typing than Mathematica, and may be able to determine whether `f` is a function, a variable or something else, and if it's a function, whether it takes one or multiple arguments.  In Mathematica, all symbols are "the same"—they don't have a specific type—and [everything is an expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html). This brings many advantages and conveniences, but in this case it makes what you want impossible to implement robustly: How would you know that `f` is a function and `a` is a variable?

You can come up with some workarounds such as using a different notation for function addition than for number addition, e.g.

```
functionAdd[f_, g_] := f[#] + g[#] &

CirclePlus[args__] := Fold[functionAdd, {args}]
```

We can say that `\[CirclePlus]` is meant for one-argument numerical functions only, and leave it to the users to comply with this. Then you can write `f \[CirclePlus] g`.

But overall I do not recommend doing such things. In the end it provides opportunities for more mistakes without giving you much of a convenience ...